# Compiling Android from source, error

Tags: android, ubuntu, compilation

I wanted to compile Lollipop from source and after many hardwork, I have successfully downloaded the repo and syncing tree process has been done successfully, but when I run the command "lunch" it gives me the list of the devices, but when I select the device it gives me the error, the full error log given below, look into it and help me

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng

```
 2. aosp_arm64-eng
 3. aosp_mips-eng
 4. aosp_mips64-eng
 5. aosp_x86-eng
 6. aosp_x86_64-eng
 7. aosp_shamu-userdebug
 8. mini_emulator_mips-userdebug
 9. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
 10. mini_emulator_arm-userdebug
 11. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
 12. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
 13. aosp_manta-userdebug
 14. cm_skyrocket-eng
 15. aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
 16. aosp_mako-userdebug
 17. aosp_deb-userdebug
 18. full_fugu-userdebug
 19. aosp_fugu-userdebug
 20. aosp_flo-userdebug
 21. aosp_grouper-userdebug
 22. aosp_tilapia-userdebug
```

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 14
build/core/envsetup.mk:94: *** Unable to determine HOST_ARCH from uname -sm: Linux i686!. Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_skyrocket'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Compiling Android is not supported on 32-bit OS, try to compile a 64-bit OS.

And do not forget to install the required packages to compile:

For 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs \
  x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos python-markdown \
  libxml2-utils xsltproc minicom tftpd uboot-mkimage expect
```

For 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 :

```
 $ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 openjdk-6-jdk tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386 \
  minicom tftpd uboot-mkimage expect libgl1-mesa-dri

  $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

And Oracle JDK 7 need install.

Comment: I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 and i have already installed the required packages, but i dont know why this error continues to pop up, one more thing that i am doing this in virtual box

Comment: it says sub-virtualbox 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.01.1-ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:45:15 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux